# Can I load balance with javascript?

Tags: javascript, load-balancing

I have 4 servers with the same application on each. My load balancer on the network is a simple round-robin. The problem is if one of the apps is down the load balancer still tries to connect to it and then returns an http error to my users.

Is there a way in javascript that I can call one server and if I get an error, then call the next server?

thanks

Comment: Usually LBs can check health of the servers and remove them from rotation.

Comment: Questions on [SO] should generally relate to specific coding problems you are having. You have not posted any code, nor have you shown [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) which makes this question either off topic or too localized.

Comment: You think it should be done in your JS, rather your code for that matter?

Comment: You are trying to fix the problem in the wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

The real answer here has to be to fix or replace the load balancer, since a load balancer that routes calls to a dead server is not...useful... :-)

But answering the question you actually asked:

The short answer is probably "no," but read on.

The long answer is it might depend on what you mean by "call." If you mean calling the server via ajax, then to do that you'd have to set up the servers to support [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) (and require your users to use [browsers compatible with it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors)), since otherwise you'll be blocked by the SOP. But if you did this, basically it would be that if you got an error in response to an ajax call to the load-balanced address, you'd try again using a specific server address.

You can do much the same thing loading images (respond to the `error` event by trying again with a specific address).

But that won't help you if your users are just following a link to your load-balanced address or any of several other things, which brings us back to: This really needs to be fixed at a load-balancer level.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the load balancer, it should have the ability to fail over to other hosts in the event that one is unavailable. Typically, you would setup a status page (if web-based) or a port to monitor and if it is unavailable the load balancer will automatically remove the host from the pool and transfer all sessions to the other hosts (again, this is assuming a web-based application).

The next layer down to try this out would be on the server level. If this is a web-based application, most web-servers come with some heartbeat functionality that you could use to fail over to other web-servers.

Doing it client-side (unless your talking about server compiled JS) would be your last recourse if the other options are not available. However, we would need more information about your application before helping further.